# Exponential of the zero matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

It is well-known that the exponential of the zero matrix is the identity matrix, but I tried to prove the opposite implication, and I failed. Can you help me to show that $e^A =I$ implies $A =0$ ?

Many thanks!!

Comment: It doesn't. Consider $e^{tA}$ for $A = \Bigl(\begin{smallmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{smallmatrix}\Bigr)$.

Comment: Thanks to everyone! The (negative) answer surprised me a lot!

Comment: False even in dimension 1: $\forall n\in\Bbb N$: $e^{2n\pi i} = 1$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If we consider matrices with complex entries an obvious counterexample is:
$$
A=2k\pi i\begin{bmatrix}
m&0\\0&n
\end{bmatrix}
$$
with $k,m,n$ integers.

For a matrix with real entries a counterexample is:
$$
A=2k\pi \begin{bmatrix}
0&-1\\1&0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
as suggested by the comment of @Daniel Fisher.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $A$ is diagonalizable with $t_1,t_2,...t_n$ as its eigenvalues and $P$ is the corresponding modal matrix. Then

$A=P^{-1}$.diag$[t_1,t_2,...t_n]$.$P$

$\implies e^A=P^{-1}$.diag$[e^{t_1},e^{t_2},....,e^{t_n}]$.$P$

$\implies P.e^A.P^{-1}=$diag$[e^{t_1},e^{t_2},....,e^{t_n}]$

$\implies I=$diag$[e^{t_1},e^{t_2},....,e^{t_n}]$

$\implies e^{t_r}=1$ for $1\leq r\leq n$

$\implies t_r=2πik_r$ , $r\in\mathbb Z$

So, $A\neq 0$ necessarily.